# Browserify module not found with recursive require (post-Babel transpile)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify, babeljs

I have the Browserify entry-file ***index.js*** that imports from a file in the same directory and the the 'render' function from 'react-dom', which is installed in `node_modules` (see ***Package.json*** for versioning) --

```
// index.js
import { Header } from './header'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

render(<Header />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I also have another file ***header.js*** which imports 'react' and creates a simple React class --

```
// header.js
import React from 'react'

export const Header = React.createClass({
    render:() => {
        return (
            <div>
                some header title
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

I use Babel to transpile es6 code so the "import" statements map to the necessary "require" statements. As far as I can tell this step is working properly. After transpiling with Babel, I use Browserify to package all the dependencies into a single file. The problem I am running into is I'm getting an *"Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined"* once I attempt to render the packaged javascript.

It looks like imports work fine in ***index.js*** but are not being resolved properly in ***header.js***. For example, if I `import React from 'react'` in ***index.js***, everything renders properly. It looks like I'm having an issue with recursive requires, but I can't seem to figure out why that is the case. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I would be glad to supply more information as well.

For reference, here is an excerpt from my ***Package.json*** --

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "~6.1.18",
    "babel-register": "~6.2.0",
    "history": "^1.12.0",
    "material-ui": "^0.13.4",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-router": "~1.0.0",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "~11.2.0",
    "del": "^2.1.0",
    "express": "~4.13.3",
    "express-urlrewrite": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-babel": "~6.1.1",
    "gulp-print": "~2.0.1",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.1",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is for questions about a Python library with that name.

Comment: Apologies, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, if I `import React from 'react'` in index.js, everything renders properly

Every file that uses JSX syntax (e.g. `<Header />`) needs to import React. You get the error because you are not doing that in `index.js` and it works once you are doing it.

If you'd look at the compiled code, you will see that `<Header />` is converted to `React.createElement(Header)`.